# send data by post method without control back to page using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am sending json string using jquery post method to other page but it return control back to index page what can i do to send data with out control back to main page

this is what i am doing

```
$('#button').click(function(){
     $.post("generator.php",
      {
          jsondata: JSON.stringify(objarray)
       },
       function(data,status){
        //alert("Data: " + data + "\nStatus: " + status);
      });
});
```

is this possible to send data by jquery post method without getting control back because i never want to show anything but move to next page from generator.php

Comment: So you don't really want to use ajax, but simply POST a form instead? I think you just overcomplicated things.

Comment: yes i just want to post jsonstring

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/133925/javascript-post-request-like-a-form-submit